# Office Excel Add-Ins (Office.js) Sign in Dialog not working in MS Teams on Macro enabled excel (.xlsm)

Tags: office-js, microsoft-teams

We have developed Excel Add-In in which sign in initiates inside Dialog (Office.js Dialog). In Desktop Excel sign in works fine for Macro enabled excel. However, same macro enabled excel (.xlsm) file when we try to open from MS Teams then Sign in functionality (Office.js Dialog) gets blocked. MS Teams doesn't allow to open office dialog. It opens a new browser instance. Same Excel add-in sign in functionality works fine for (.xlsx) from MS Teams.

Comment: Could you please share repro steps or any reference docs.

Comment: 1. Create new workbook and save as "xslm"
2. Create Excel Add-In with sign in dialog
3. Open MS Teams
4. Upload xslm file under Files tab of one of the Team
5. Open workbook in Desktop Teams
6. Initiate Excel Add-In. Add In Sign-in Office..js dialog will block in Teams

Comment: How are you creating "Excel Add-In with sign in dialog". Could you please share any reference docs which you are following.

Comment: Also could you please follow MS Teams guidance for Excel Add-In support.